# Creating 2 Random Matrices in C using malloc and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, random

I have an assignment to create two randomly generated matrices of size `n` (where `n` = 4, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192) and multiply these matrices.

I am creating the matrices using `malloc`. I'm using just `long** intCreateMatrix(n)`
function to create both the matrices `A` and `B`. This function returns a pointer to the matrix. Another function 
`long** intInitializeMatirx(a,n)` is used to initialize the matrix with random values.

When I call these functions for two different matrices it prints the same contents of matrix for both the matrices.The code is given below:

```
void intAlgo(int n,int algo){

    long **a;
    long **b;
    long **c;

    a = intCreateMatrix(n);
    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    a = intInitializeMatrix(a,n);

    b = intCreateMatrix(n);
    printf("Matrix B:\n");
    b = intInitializeMatrix(b,n);

}

long** intCreateMatrix(int n){

    long **arr;
    int i,j;
    arr = (long **)malloc(n * sizeof(long *));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        arr[i] = (long *)malloc(n * sizeof(long));
    return arr;

}

long** intInitializeMatrix(long **arr,int n){

    int i,j;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            arr[i][j] = rand()%10;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%ld ",arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return arr;
    free (arr);

}
```

`intAlgo` is the function that calls the `createMatrix` and Initialises matrix.

`CreateMAtrix` takes n as input and returns a pointer to the matrix created using `malloc`.

`InitialiseMatrix` initializes the matrix using rand function and prints the matrix and returns the matrix.

When I execute it `a` and `b` should have different values 
but they have the same values example I'm getting these values for Matrix `A` and `B? :

Matrix `A`:

```
0 7 2 3 

0 6 3 1 

7 2 0 2 

6 3 2 6
```

Matrix `B`:

```
0 7 2 3 

0 6 3 1 

7 2 0 2 

6 3 2 6
```

These two matrices should be different I'm not sure where 
I am going wrong. Could you please guide me?

Comment: Call `srand()` **once** not for every time you call it.

Comment: Thank you so much :) it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`srand(int)` is used for seeding the pseudo-random number generator. Each time `rand()` is seeded with the same seed, it must produce the same sequence of values. It should be seeded once before calling `rand()`. It should not be
repeatedly seeded, or reseeded. Call `srand(time(0));` once before you start calling `initializeMatrix` in `main()`.

Also after `return` statement writing code is meaningless - control never reaches those lines. And why do you want to free it there? Free it after you are done working with it. You still needed them for printing the values stored in those dynamically allocated memories.

Casting the `malloc` is unnecessary but checking the return value of `malloc` is *not*. You should be checking it.

Comment: free() is code error i forgot to change it while i was trying it without return type.... btw thank you so much i tried the srand just once and got it :)